# How can I call the function once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a project in react native and I need to read data from a firebase db in realtime.
I try to:

```
const [numberTrains, setNumberTrains] = useState(0)
 function Read(){
    const starCountRef = ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId);
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      setNumberTrains(data.countTrains);   
    });
  }
  Read()
    console.log(numberTrains)
```

But it throws the exception: `Error: Too many re-renders.` React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
And the output looks like:

```
 LOG  0
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
 LOG  1
```

How can I read data in `numberTrain` only once?

Comment: call `Read` function in an `useEffect` hook with `empty dependencies`

Comment: How? I also didn't use hooks

Comment: Yes, use `useEffect` hook to call `Read` function only once when the component loads. As of now, `Read` is being called on every render and the state gets updated, and triggers another re-render, and hence the error `Too many re-renders`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use useEffect**

```
const [numberTrains, setNumberTrains] = useState(0)

function Read(){
  const starCountRef = ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId);
  onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    setNumberTrains(data.countTrains);   
  });
}

React.useEffect(()=>{
  Read();
  console.log(numberTrains)
},[]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
useEffect(()=>{
  Read()
},[])
```

it will only call one time suggestion if data is only one time put a check for numberTrains length before calling read